# 4 column VLOOKUP in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I would like to do the following in Excel

```
IF(any cell in Column D = any cell in Column C AND any cell in Column B = any cell in Column A)
Display TRUE in Column E
```

Would it be best to use a VLOOKUP here or an IF?

Hope this explains what I need!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use COUNTIF() like this:

In cell F1

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)
```

and drag that down for all of column F

In cell G1

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,C1)
```

and drag that down for all of column G

Then in your result cell

```
=IF(SUM(SUM(F:F),SUM(G:G)) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```